# create dataframe or list with dynamic json records

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create a dataframe or list that contains within each record a JSON schema that I will later insert through Rest-API. I have a sample that I'm trying to run but it doesn't work, I leave the code:

```
data_collect = df_res.collect()

for row in data_collect:
  v_id_person = '"' + row["Id"] + '"' 
  i= 1
  data[i] = """{
    "resourceType" : "Example",
    "identifier" : [{ 
            "use" : "official", 
             {
                    "system": "https://example/identif",
                    "code": "CC"
                }
            ] }, 
            "value" : """ +    str(v_id_person)   + """
    } """
  i = i + 1

display(data)
```

As I mentioned, the previous code does not achieve the objective of creating a list with the JSON structure for each record of the "FOR" cycle

What I want to achieve is:

```
display(data)
row[1] = {"resourceType" : "Example", "identifier" : [{ ... "value": 5412"
row[2] = {"resourceType" : "Example", "identifier" : [{ ... "value": 432"
row[3] = {"resourceType" : "Example", "identifier" : [{ ... "value": 1112"
...
row[n] = {"resourceType" : "Example", "identifier" : [{ ... "value": v_id_person
```

"
What do you recommend me to do?

From already thank you for your time.

Regards

Comment: Can you share your json structure that you want to convert to dataframe ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to add the json structure that appears posted, this for each record in the new dataframe "data", thanks

Comment: I am not able to get you. Can you please write what you have and what you want i.e. input, output and expected_output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with this

```
data = []
for row in data_collect:
  data.append(f"""{{
    "resourceType" : "Example",
    "identifier" : [{{ 
            "use" : "official", 
             {{
                    "system": "https://example/identif",
                    "code": "CC"
                }}
            ] }}, 
            "value" : "{row['Id']}"
    }} """)
```

Comment: thanks you for response. I try to implement you comment, but return error "f-string: expressions nested too deeply". I try resolve this. If you have any other comment, I would appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: @Gonza My bad. I have edited the answer now check

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now I can run as I wanted. I have a query about it: is this that I just created a dataframe? why doesn't it work for me with the display() function but it does with print() ?? Thank you!!

Comment: For that you need to show the display function.

Comment: because I want to validate the data, since I will create a much larger json. How can I see the structured dataframe type diplsya()? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me the display function you have implemented ?

Comment: the moment only Display(data) or Print(data), but this funtions show data out of order, with line break "\n". What kind of data frame is it? how can I structure the output? Here is an example of how it appears now:
'{\n    "resourceType" : "Example",\n    "identifier" : [{ \n    ...."

Comment: Finally I convert the list to pandas dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create DataFrame from json using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("data.json")
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks for you response. I've posted an edit to the expected output.